# Is there a cross-db Rails way to get the unix timestamp representation of updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We are testing a MySQL -> Postgres (and am a Postgres noob) migration and have the following:

```
select(['id','name','concat(unix_timestamp(updated_at)) as timestamp']).order('position asc')
```

It looks like the Postgres way would be:

```
select(['id','name','extract(epoch from updated_at) as timestamp']).order('position asc')
```

Is there a cross-db or hopefully Rails way of getting an integer representation of an updated_at time?

Answer (score 0):

How about just use `to_i` method to receive unix timestamp use something like this:

```rb
YourModel.select(:id, :name, :updated_at).order(position: :asc).each do |your_model|
  timestamp = your_model.updated_at.to_i
  # other code
end
```

It should works fine with MySQL and Postgres.